# Performance testing on VMWARE

Tags: vmware

I want to run performance tests on my application and report CPU utilization and memory utilization for the app. For this I need to have fixed CPU cycles available to the VM running the app, otherwise the results will of tests will be non-repeatable. This basically means I want to be able to partition the CPU between the VMs running various apps on a ESX server; just as one can partition the memory between VMs on an ESX box. Is there a way to do that. Has anyone done performance testing on VMs and produced repeatable results.

Answer (score 0):

For repeatable and good results you should run it on a standard system where you control the entire environment. If you have to run it in a VM then make that the only VM that is running. The more variables there are in the equation the harder it is to get repeatable results.